# CSS, html checkbox на ширину строки таблицы

Tags: html, css

У меня такой вопрос, как можно сделать невидимый чекбокс на всю ширину строки в таблице?

```css
.ips_table {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.ips_table_content {
 display: table-row-group;
}

.ips_table_head {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #222;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: table-row;
}

.ips_table_desc {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 15px;
}

.ips_table_user {
 display: table-row;
 color: #222; 
    line-height: 18px;
}

.ips_user_desc {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 10px;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
   position: absolute;

}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .ips_table_user{
 background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
   <div class="ips_table_content">
    <div class="ips_table_head">
        <div class="ips_table_desc">Delete</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="ips_table_user">
    <div class="ips_user_desc"><label for="toggle"></label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle"></div>
    <div class="ips_user_desc">Name</div>
    <div class="ips_user_desc">01 Feb 2017 00:00</div>
    <div class="ips_user_desc">777</div>
    <div class="ips_user_desc">123</div>
    <div class="ips_user_desc">test</div>
    </div>
    
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Использовать `<label>` (правда, так делать нельзя, спецификация html не позволяет этого):

```css
.ips_table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.ips_table_content {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.ips_table_head {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: table-row;
}

.ips_table_desc {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px;
}

.ips_table_user {
  display: table-row;
  color: #222;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.ips_user_desc {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.ips_table_user {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ips_table_content">
  <div class="ips_table_head">
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Delete</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
    <div class="ips_table_desc">Head-Text</div>
  </div>


  <label class="ips_table_user">
    <div class="ips_user_desc"><label for="toggle"><input type="checkbox" id="toggle"></div>
        <div class="ips_user_desc">Name</div>
        <div class="ips_user_desc">01 Feb 2017 00:00</div>
        <div class="ips_user_desc">777</div>
        <div class="ips_user_desc">123</div>
        <div class="ips_user_desc">test</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Как более правильный вариант используйте javascript, чтобы вызывать клик при нажатии на строку псевдо-таблицы

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за ответ и совет)